# Where to install plugins created with Qt 6.5 in Debian?

Tags: debian, qt6, qtplugin

I don't know where should I put my plugin that I created to see it in Qt Designer

I installed Qt 6.5 in Debian and created a custom widget (plugin) with Qt Creator.
Where should I copy the compiled .so file so that Qt Designer can see it among the widgets ?